# Riemann integrals of abstract functions into Banach spaces

Tags: real-analysis, integration, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

If we define the (Riemann) integral of an *abstract function*, i.e. a function $f:[a,b]\to Y$ where $Y$ is a Banach space, as$$\int_a^b F(t)dt:=\lim_{\max(t_{k+1}-t_k)\to 0}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(t_{k+1}-t_k)F(\xi_k)$$where $a=t_0<t_1<\ldots<t_n=b$ is one of the partitions whose intervals' maximum length approaches $0$, I read two unproved statement in Kolmogorov-Fomin's (p. 486 [here](http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf)) which I find very interesting:

- If $F$ is continuous, then it is integrable. The text says that the proof is analogous to the case $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$, but all the proofs I have found for the real-valued case rely on Darboux sums where maxima and minima and other properties of the real numbers are used, while we have values in a general Banach space, here.
- If $U:Y\to Z$ is a linear map between two Banach spaces then $\int_a^b UF(t)dt=U\int_a^bF(t)dt$ for any integrable $F$.

I have searched a lot in the web, but I find no proofs of these statements. Could anybody write a proof, the most elementary possible, since Kolmogorov-Fomin's explains very few things about such integral, or give a link to one? I thank you for any answer!

Comment: Riemann integral is not well behaved even for scalar valued case. I see no reason to waste time on its generalizations. Better take a look at Bochner and Pettis integrals. If you are brave enough look at [Vector Measures. Joseph Diestel, John Jerry Uhl](http://books.google.ru/books/about/Vector_Measures.html?id=NCm4E2By8DQC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: For the first statement use the facts that $F$ is uniformly continuous and $Y$ is complete.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo How can we use that? I'm trying to teach myself some analysis, but I don't attend university for the moment and have a humanities-oriented background, so my tools are really elementary (with a bit of topology, if that helps). If you liked to produce an answer I'd be very grateful to you! Thank you both for the comments!

Comment: Is [Krantz _The Integral_ (2011)](http://books.google.it/books?id=YFJAsDhprvYC&printsec=frontcover&dq=krantz+the+integral&hl=it&sa=X&ei=U6uGVI7uJsL-UvevgWA&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=krantz%20the%20integral&f=false), p. 9 enough ? Let me know.

Comment: @TonyPiccolo Perfect: it's literaly the same proof for a complete normed space $Y$. I'd never found a proof based on that argument. I $\infty$-ly thank you!

Comment: For the second statement the integral is the limit of a sum of products by scalars, $U$ is linear so $\dots$

Comment: See [Drabek,Milota _Methods of Nonlinear Analysis_ (2013)](https://books.google.it/books?id=_bVDAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA110&dq=linear+operator+riemann+integral&hl=it&sa=X&ei=jryMVIvBKeeqywPU9oGICQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=linear%20operator%20riemann%20integral&f=false), proposition 3.1.3.(i), p. 110 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one commenter pointed out, in *The Integral* by Krantz, to show that continuous functions into a Banach space $X$ are integrable, we can essentially mimic the proof given for real-valued functions.

More precisely, we first define the integral of $f:I\to X$ by declaring that if there exists an element $I\in X$ such that for each $\varepsilon>0$ and each partition $\mathcal P$ of $I$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that whenever the mesh of the partition $\mathcal P$ is $<\delta$, we have that $\lVert \mathcal R(f,\mathcal P) - I\rVert < \varepsilon$. We declare that $I = \int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

This is a good definition because the norm on Banach spaces makes them into metric spaces, so if $I$ exists, it is unique.

Now if $f$ is continuous, we can prove it is integrable mimicking the proof for real-valued functions by showing that $\{\mathcal R(\mathcal P_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence for some appropriate choice of partitions with $\operatorname{mesh}\mathcal P_n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

A corollary of this is (cf. Pugh's book *Real Mathematical Analysis*)

**$C^1$ Mean Value Theorem** If $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ is open, and $f:U\to\mathbb R^m$ is of class $C^1$, so the map $Df:\mathbb R^n\to \mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ exists and is continuous, and if the segment $[p,q]$ is contained in $U$ then
$$
f(q) - f(p) = T(q-p).
$$
where $T$ is the **average derivative** of $f$ on the segment,
$$
T = \int_0^1(Df)_{p+t(q-p)}\,dt.
$$
The proof is the fact that $\mathcal L(\mathbb R^n,\mathbb R^m)$ is a Banach space and an application of our corollary.