# Riemann integral in a Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, riemann-integration, frechet-derivative

Let $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow E$ be a continuous function that takes value in a Banach space $E$. I know that we can define the integral $\int^x_0 f(t)dt, \forall x \in [0,\infty)$ using Riemann procedure just like in the real case, a post that I consulted can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1057490/riemann-integrals-of-abstract-functions-into-banach-spaces) . Although I'm just new to the theory, still I would like to know that how we can prove the map

$$ [0,\infty) \ni x \mapsto \int^x_0f(t)dt \in E$$

is continuous and differentiable, with the Frechet derivative at $x_0$ equal to $f(x_0)$. This is not easy for me with the basic knowledge of Banach spaces. Any suggestions, outline of the proof or any basic reference on the properties of this integral are pretty much appreciated!

For the context, I read Brezis' book, chapter 7, where he gave a general theorem of Cauchy, Lipchitz and Picard and encountered this notion of integral in his proof.

The Frechet derivative is defined to be

$$F'(t):= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{F(t+h)-F(t)}{h},$$

provided the limit in $E$ exists and is unique.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you only want a hint, so i will only give one. If you need more information i can give further hints.

Note that
$F^\prime (t)$ being the derivative at $t$ is equivalent to
$F(t+h) = F(t) + F^\prime(t) h + \mathcal{o}(h)$ using the little-$o$ notation.

Show that for $a,b \in [0,\infty)$ with $a \leq b$ it is true that
$$\| \int_a^b f(t) dt \| \leq \max_{t \in [a,b]}\| f(t) \| (b-a) .$$

Use this and some of the intuitive rules for the integral (you may have to prove) to show that $F(t+h) - F(t) - f(t) h  = o(h)$, where $F$ is defined by $F(t) = \int_0^t f(t^\prime) dt^\prime $.

Comment: So for OP: the exact proof you learnt in the real-valued case holds here. You just need to prove the relevant properties of the integral once again (linearity, norm bounds etc)

Comment: Thank you all! so I have tried to prove the integral is additive: $\int^x_0 +\int^y_x = \int^y_0$ and then use this to derive $ \int^{t+h}_0-\int^{t}_0 =  \int^{t+h}_t $. Next I use your triangle inequality like you showed above to derive $ h^{-1}\| \int^{t+h}_t f(s)ds - f(t) \| \rightarrow 0 $. Am I correct?

Comment: @JeffreyJao You need to multiply $f(t)$ by $h$ but otherwise yes. Although you may want to use another small trick before using the inequality to obtain $\to 0$.

Comment: So I got $\| h^{-1} \int^{t+h}_t (f(s) -f(t))ds \| \leq \max_{[t,t+h]}\| f(s) -f(t)\| \rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$, I don't see where the small trick is...?

Comment: @JeffreyJao that is the small trick (putting $f(t)$ into the integral).

Comment: @jd27 Ahh, I thought I misunderstood sth :D, thank you by the way!